# Unix bash - using cut to regex lines in a file, match regex result with another similar line

Tags: bash, unix

I have a text file: file.txt, with several thousand lines. It contains a lot of junk lines which I am not interested in, so I use the cut command to regex for the lines I am interested in first. For each entry I am interested in, it will be listed twice in the text file: Once in a "definition" section, another in a "value" section. I want to retrieve the first value from the "definition" section, and then for each entry found there find it's corresponding "value" section entry.

The first entry starts with ' gl_ ', while the 2nd entry would look like ' "gl_ ', starting with a '"'.

This is the code I have so far for looping through the text document, which then retrieves the values I am interested in and appends them to a .csv file:

```
while read -r line
do
    if [[ $line == gl_* ]] ; then (param=$(cut -d'\' -f 1 $line) | def=$(cut -d'\' -f 2 $line) | type=$(cut -d'\' -f 4 $line) | prompt=$(cut -d'\' -f 8 $line))
    while read -r glline
    do
        if [[ $glline == '"'$param* ]] ; then val=$(cut -d'\' -f 3 $glline) |
        "$project";"$param";"$val";"$def";"$type";"$prompt" >> /filepath/file.csv
    done < file.txt
done < file.txt
```

This seems to throw some syntax errors related to unexpected tokens near the first 'done' statement.

Example of text that needs to be parsed, and paired:

```
gl_one\User Defined\1\String\1\\1\Some Text 
gl_two\User Defined\1\String\1\\1\Some Text also 
gl_three\User Defined\1\Time\1\\1\Datetime now
some\junk 
"gl_one\1\Value1 
some\junk 
"gl_two\1\Value2
"gl_three\1\Value3
```

So effectively, the while loop reads each line until it hits the first line that starts with 'gl_', which then stores that value (ie. gl_one) as a variable 'param'.
It then starts the nested while loop that looks for the line that starts with a ' " ' in front of the gl_, and is equivalent to the 'param' value. In other words, the
script should couple the lines gl_one and "gl_one, gl_two and "gl_two, gl_three and "gl_three.

The text file is large, and these are settings that have been defined this way. I need to collect the values for each gl_ parameter, to save them together in a .csv file with their corresponding "gl_ values.

Wanted regex output stored in variables would be something like this:

first while loop:
$param = gl_one, $def = User Defined, $type = String, $prompt = Some Text

second while loop:
$val = Value1

Then it stores these variables to the file.csv, with semi-colon separators.

Currently, I have an error for the first 'done' statement, which seems to indicate an issue with the quotation marks. Apart from this,
I am looking for general ideas and comments to the script. I.e, not entirely sure I am looking for the quotation mark parameters "gl_ correctly, or if the
semi-colons as .csv separators are added correctly.

Edit: Overall, the script runs now, but extremely slow due to the inner while loop. Is there any faster way to match the two lines together and add them to the .csv file?

Any ideas and comments?

Comment: `if ....; then....; fi` Also you could add a desired output.

Comment: https://shellcheck.net to validate your script. Just a quick look, you might need to use a different `fd` for the while loop, does not matter if it is the inner or the outer loop. They just need to use a different `fd`.

Comment: The file directory should be correct, it's just ambiguous in the above example. Thanks, I will check the script at the link site

Comment: Could the inner while loop and if statement be replaced with a grep statement in some way? I find the inner while loop to be too cumbersome for the system, as it runs for 20+mins now to loop through all the lines for each line.

Comment: It seems that ‘gl_’ and ‘“gl_” are the only things you know about the item/s you’re searching for. Are the ‘one’, ‘two’, ‘three’ etc just examples or can they be something else?

Comment: They are just examples. I need to collect all instances of gl_someParameter with it's "gl_someParameter counterpart

Comment: A quick way of reducing the work of your loop, would be to create a temporary input file using grep: `cat file.txt | grep “gl_” | sort > tmp.txt` (and using that as the input to `read`)

Comment: Are the '\1\'s in your example literals or can they vary?

Comment: They are literals, not sure what they mean, but they do not vary between the instances.

Comment: I'd be interested to know how you got on with this.

Comment: Good. I realised after I posted that my awk print is a bit clunky and could be modified to `awk -F\\ -v OFS=\; '{print $1,$5,$7,$NF}'` to get the same results. If you want any further explanations about how component parts work then do come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will generate a file containing the data you want:

`cat file.txt | grep gl_ | sed -E "s/\"//" | sort | sed '$!N;s/\n/\\/' | awk -F'\' '{print $1"; "$5"; "$7"; "$NF}' > /filepath/file.csv`

- It uses `grep` to extract all lines containing 'gl_'
- then `sed` to remove the leading '"' from the lines that contain one [I have assumed there are no further '"' in the line]
- The lines are sorted
- `sed` removes the return from each pair of lines
- `awk` then prints
  the required columns according to your requirements
- Output routed to the file.

Comment: Cheers! Gonna try working with this. This won't by any chance remove the source file.txt?

Comment: `cat` just reads the contents of the file and outputs it. It's totally non-destructive.

Comment: your `sort` may put value before definition in some cases

Comment: I suppose it's possible if the value of "User Defined" is less than '1' - or have you spotted something else?

Comment: I determined with the OP that it's always '1'

Comment: I think it sorts after numeric doesn't it? I'm pretty sure that the only values that would sort before 1 would be: 0 / . - , + * ) ( ' & % $ # " ! and space.

Answer (score 0):

```
LANG=C sort -t\\ -sd -k1,1 <file.txt |\
sed '
  /^gl_/{             # if definition
    N;                #   append next line to buffer
    s/\n"gl_[^\\]*//; #   if value, strip first column
    t;                #   and start next loop
  }
  D;                  # otherwise, delete the line
' |\
awk -F\\ -v p="$project" -v OFS=\; '{print p,$1,$10,$2,$4,$8 }' \
>>/filepath/file.csv
```

- `sort` lines so `gl_...` appears immediately before `"gl_...` (`LANG` fixes `LC_TYPE`) - assumes definition appears before value
- `sed` to help ensure matching definition and value (may still fail if duplicate/missing value), and tidy for awk
- `awk` to pull out relevant fields

Comment: Aren't you overlooking fact that the file doesn't contain just the lines in the example?

Comment: If the line doesn't start `gl_` then it gets deleted (`D`).

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. Thanks for clarifying.